# (Python) Import argument from __init__ in one module for use in another?

Tags: python

I'm really new to Python and have been using it in conjunction with Scrapy for making some web crawlers. When running a spider from the terminal I can use "-a NAME=VALUE" to set arguments, which is especially useful for directing it to different domains. I'm trying use the "domain" argument as a variable in another module but got stuck. Here's a portion of the module I'm trying to import the argument from:

```
class Spider(spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = 'changelog'
    rules = (spiders.Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)

    def __init__(self, domain='WHAT_IM_TRYING_TO_FIND', *args, **kwargs):
        super(Spider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.domain = domain
        self.allowed_domains = [domain]
        self.start_urls = [
            'http://%s/' % domain,
            'http://%s/index.html' % domain,
            'http://%s/index.php' % domain,
        ]
```

In a separate module, trying things like

```
from MyModule import Spider

variable = Spider.domain
```

or

```
variable = __import __ ('MyModule').Spider.domain
```

gives me

```
Class 'Spider' has no 'domain' member
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Scrapy's file structure looks like this:

```
myproject/
__init __.py
items.py
pipelines.py
settings.py
spiders/
    __init __.py
    spider.py
```

Comment: In that file structure, which is the file where you are trying to access `domain`?

Comment: I'm trying to access `domain` in `pipelines.py`, and `domain` is from `class Spider` within `spider.py`.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146341/scrapy-access-spider-class-variable-in-pipeline-init)?  That suggests you can't access the spider instance even when the pipeline is being created, let alone when the pipleine module is being imported.  You may need to delve more deeply into the Scrapy docs to understand what is happening in what order and at what point you actually can/should access the spider object.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. What I'm trying to do is name the table created in MySQL by `modules.py` after the `domain` argument, but it looks like I'll have to find another way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`domain` is an attribute of instances of Spider, not of the Spider class.  You can only access `domain` if you have an instance of `Spider` created somewhere.

Comment: the module trying to access `domain` is triggered by `Spider`, so it should be able to access the `domain` attribute, I'm just not sure how to do so. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianTL: You'll need to give some more details about that.  When Spider "triggers" your module, does it give it any information about Spiders it has already created?

Comment: Hopefully I can explain myself well enough. The Scrapy project has the following file structure: edit: added to original question

When the spider is executed, items it scrapes are passed to `pipelines.py` which handles how they are processed. `pipelines.py` imports classes from `models.py`, which is where I want to access `domain` from.

Basically `Spider` returns an item, which is passed through `pipelines.py`, and the process repeats for each item.